# When clicking next to a coloured string, richtextbox makes me use that color instead of black

Tags: c#, .net

I have a richTextBox that I use so the user can see the XML file they have and let them edit it. I have some code that changes keywords colours into a colour I specify. This is the method that I use:

```
private void CheckKeyword(string word, Color color, int startIndex)
    {
        if (this.richTextBox.Text.Contains(word))
        {
            int index = -1;
            int selectStart = this.richTextBox.SelectionStart;
            while ((index = this.richTextBox.Text.IndexOf(word, (index + 1))) != -1)
            {
                this.richTextBox.Select((index + startIndex), word.Length);
                this.richTextBox.SelectionColor = color;
                this.richTextBox.Select(selectStart, 0);
                this.richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I click 
[near a coloured string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDLDX.png), I start typing [in that specific colour.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIgmg.png)

I know why its happening, but don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to determine whether or not your cursor is "inside" a keyword area or not at KeyDown, so wire up the KeyDown event and try using this code.  I'm sure there's a more efficient way to determine whether or not your cursor is inside a bracketed keyword, but this seems to get the job done:

```
void rtb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  int openIndex = rtb.Text.Substring(0, rtb.SelectionStart).LastIndexOf('<');
  if (openIndex > -1) {
    int endIndex = rtb.Text.IndexOf('>', openIndex);
    if (endIndex > -1) {
      if (endIndex + 1 <= this.rtb.SelectionStart) {
        rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
      } else {
        string keyWord = rtb.Text.Substring(openIndex + 1, endIndex - openIndex - 1);
        if (keyWord.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '<', '>' }) == -1) {
          this.rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
        } else {
          this.rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
        }
      }
    } else {
      this.rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
    }
  } else {
    this.rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
  }
}
```